# Exporting the OrientDB database structure in a "command style" format

Tags: orientdb

The question is - is there any way to export the OrientDB database structure in a command style format, like:

```
create database <name>
create class <name>
create property <name>...
```

etc.

Thanks,
Denis

Answer (score 1):

There is a command `export schema` available in orientdb console, it produces something like:

```
...
"schema":{
    "version":54,
    "classes":[
        {
            "name":"YourClassName",
            "default-cluster-id":9,
            "cluster-ids":[
                9
            ],
            "properties":[
                {
                    "name":"f1",
                    "type":"STRING"
                },
                {
                    "name":"f2",
                    "type":"STRING"
                },
                {
                    "name":"f3",
                    "type":"STRING"
                }
            ]
        },
...
```

The output is json, so you can write a script to transform it in whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

More generally: `export database FILENAME` exports in a (special) JSON format (special, because the ordering of keys is important for it to be readable by OrientDB).